# Is it safe to use the Keccak Algorithm to create the Key for a Serpent cipher?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash

I like to store some configuration but would encrypt them with the Serpent cipher.
Is it safe to do this? When not, what is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a key with a hash function. You create a key with *randomness*. Or, maybe, you *derive* a key from another secret value, using a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function).

A symmetric encryption algorithm is normally defined to accept "binary keys": any sequence of bits of some specific size is acceptable as a key value. When an encryption algorithm accepts a binary key, then any secure KDF which outputs such unbiased sequences of bits can be used to produce the key.

I *suspect* that you are trying to do *password-based encryption*: to derive a key from a *password*, and then use the key with a symmetric encryption algorithm. If that is the case, then do yourself a favour: use an existing protocol/format, don't try to design one yourself. These things are *subtle*. Nobody really knows how to make a *secure* protocol from the first try, or at least make sure that what they designed is secure (it cannot be tested). So the smart thing to do is to use something which has already been designed and heavily reviewed by lots of other people. I suggest [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880).

Even better, if you use a standard format, then you may hope to use an already existing library which does all the job for you. It so happens that writing a secure *implementation*, even starting from a standard protocol, is also very hard. Code which is easiest to write properly is code which has already been written properly. In the case of OpenPGP, this points to [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/). Or [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) if you work with Java.